# Creating a linked list from nodes that already have been created. Getting Seg Fault

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

So this a problem for a class that I am in. The stipulations are that we use the code below as our main **without editing it**.

```
int main(void) {

  // a reference to the head of our list
  node *head = NULL;
  node ** list = &head;

  // the nodes we will put in our list
  node a = {6,NULL};
  node b = {8,NULL};
  node c = {4,NULL};
  node d = {10,NULL};
  node e = {2,NULL};

  // build the list
  append(list, &a);
  append(list, &b);
  prepend(list, &c);
  append(list, &d);
  prepend(list, &e);

  // print the list
  print(list);

  // test the find function
  int value;
  for (value = 1; value <= 10; value++) {
    node * found = find(list, value);
    if (found == NULL)
      printf("Node %d not found...\n", value);
    else
      printf("Found node %d!\n", found->content);
  }

  // test delete function
  delete(list, 4);
  delete(list, 8);
  print(list);

  return 0;
}
```

We need to create all of the functions used in the main on our own. Currently just working on the append function. I was told the append function should look like this:`append(node * list, node * new_node);`

```
tydef stuct node_t {
  int content;
  struct node_t *next;
} node;
```

This is what I have for the node declaration.

```
void append(node ** list, node * new_nodes) {
  node ** current = list;
  while ((*current)->next != NULL) {
    (*current) = (*current)->next;
  }
  (*current)->next = new_node;
  list = current;
}
```

This is my append function. I'm relatively sure the last line is wrong but I'm at a loss as were to start. Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Comment: The best thing to do is draw a diagram of the nodes and carefully change the pointers on the diagram while reading through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since list is passed by value, you can use it as a temp variable:

```
void append(node **list, node *new_node)
{
    while(*list != NULL)
        list = &((*list)->next);
    *list = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. With a little work this got me started. I don't have enough reputation to up vote you. I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

Consider these two lines:

```
node *head = NULL;
node ** list = &head;
```

That makes `list` point to a pointer to `NULL`.

Then consider:

```
append(list, &a);
```

and (from the `append` function):

```
node ** current = list;
while ((*current)->next != NULL) {
```

You're passing a pointer to a pointer to `NULL` to the `append` function, which mean `*current` is a pointer to `NULL`, and you then dereference that `NULL` pointer leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and your crash.

Comment: Roger. So I would need to take the pointer to &a, since its the only location I have, and set it the head. Also making sure that we are at end of list for future appends?

Answer (score 0):

head and list haddn't been set yet - you have to checke first if list == NULL.

```
void append(node ** list, node * new_nodes) {
   node **current = list;
   if (*current == NULL) {
       *current = node;
       return;
   }
   while ((*current)->next != NULL) {
      (*current) = (*current)->next;
   }
   (*current)->next = new_node;
 }
```